# Python script without Blender

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to run a python script(with a Python IDE) that takes data from a Blender file and gives some results without running Blender itself?

Comment: [Blender As Python Module - Blender Developer Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule)

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with the help of Blender. but it would be nice to be able to draw, for example, a cube in Blender, import the file into the Python IDE, and check dimensions, colors, etc, change nothing inside Blender file

Comment: Fair enough, I was also wandering if the data structure that blender used could be easily interpreted. And I thought it's quite doable but the codec and the structure might differ from version to version.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile blender as a module, in another program, but there's no other way to access the Blender IDE without running blender, and running it as a module is, in a sense, still running it.

Answer (score 0):

Im a total begineer at Blender, but I've got some technical knoweldge as a developer. If you don't find any solution, I think you might be able to install blender on a remote server (with a graphical user interface). Then import your file and then find a way to expose blender operations as a server. However if the main problem is to support a better python IDE than the one embedded in the blender text editor, I have no clue for that :/

I think you might be able to import bpy in you python IDE to let it detect blender symbols (bpy.context, bpy.data ...) but you'll still have to copy/past your scripts inside text editor to run the full script